# Reduce an array of objects

Tags: javascript, filter

The object looks like this:
My `App.js` file looks like this

```
const course = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Half Stack application development",
    parts: [
      {
        name: "Fundamentals of React",
        exercises: 10,
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Using props to pass data",
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2,
      },
      {
        name: "State of a component",
        exercises: 14,
        id: 3,
      },
      {
        name: "Redux",
        exercises: 11,
        id: 4,
      },
    ],
  };
return <Course course={course} />;
```

And I want to total number of exercises filtered into `total`

```
const parts = props.Course.parts;

const total = parts.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
    return previousValue + currentValue;
  }, 0);
```

Output is shown as:

```
0[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

Comment: `return previousValue + currentValue.excercises` should probably do.

Comment: Remember `Course` (capital "C") is not the same as `course` (small "c") for JavaScript. `const parts = props.Course.parts;` should be `const parts = props.course.parts;`. Furthermore, as @WiktorZychla already pointed out, you have to access the `exercises` attribute of the current items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @wiktor-zychla, adding exercises in your reduce function will work.

```
const parts = props.course.parts;

const total = parts.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
    return previousValue + currentValue.excercises;
  }, 0);
```

**Explanation behind your original output,**

```
0[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

The above output is the result of adding object to a number. Hope this helps

Edit: There was also typo in how you are accessing `course` prop. Fixed it above